# Last mongo replica set becomes secondary?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have 3 mongo nodes set up as replica sets. The following scenario is occurring:

- Node 1 is primary, node 2 is secondary, node 3 is secondary.
- Nodes 2 and 3 get shut down.
- Node 1 becomes secondary.

This doesn't make sense to me...I would expect the primary to remain primary. Can someone explain this to me? I've read that perhaps I need an arbiter to make the election in the case that only a single node survives, however this feels clunky. Why can't a single node make the election?

Comment: How would the single node tell the difference between it being the only one alive, and others except it being alive but cannot communicate with it (i.e. partition). What you're asking for allows split-brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 3 node replicaset you need a minimum of 2 nodes up.  The docs refer to a 'majority' required to elect a new primary.  Therefore with a 3 node RS, there needs to be at least 2 nodes running for one node to be assigned as primary.

This page has a quite useful table showing the fault tolerance for replicasets with different numbers of nodes:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/